# UITableView - I want to display blank cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set up my tableView and has two `springVar` as shown in the image below. I want my tableview to show empty cells after the two `springVar` so that my solve bar is at the bottom of the screen. Any advices on how to go about it? My code is below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return springVar.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    var data : NSManagedObject = springVar[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
    cell!.textLabel!.text = "Spring \(indexPath.row + 1)"

    var force : Float = data.valueForKey("force") as! Float
    var stiffness : Float = data.valueForKey("stiffness") as! Float
    cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Force =\(force) \t Stiffness =\(stiffness)"
    cell!.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor .darkGrayColor()

    return cell!
}
```

[image: TableImage]

Comment: For this purpose . .  you should try to add bottom toolbar

Comment: I think you should use static cell if you are only using two rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add Footer view in your tableView this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //add button in your footer view
    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 30))
    button.setTitle("Solve", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.brownColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    footerView.addSubview(button)

    return footerView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

i think this maybe helpfull

```
if indexPAth.row / 2 == 0
{
    return UITableViewCell()
    // u can customize ur cell to show a button or anything else
}
```

this show a custom/blank cell after each 2 cell,(odd)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the footerHeight according to your own needs.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let footerHeight : CGFloat = (tableView.frame.size.height - (CGFloat(springVar.count) * 45.0) - 45.0 - 64.0)

    let oneCell = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: footerHeight))


    return oneCell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    let footerHeight : CGFloat = (tableView.frame.size.height - (CGFloat(springVar.count) * 45.0) - 45.0 - 64.0)

    return footerHeight
}
```